using 'copy to' command and change type postgrsql
I have a file that I want to copy into a table, the table has three columns,
create table item (
    name Text,
    t Time without time zone,
    status Text);

the File looks like this:
book, 2022-08-13 13:30:01,out
char,2022-08-13 13:35:22, inside 
lather,2022-08-13 13:36:00, out

is there a way to convert the Datetime value to time value without do a table with Datetime and then Altering it?

select '2022-08-13 13:35:22'::time; 13:35:22 . Just import it should do the cast automatically.

The CSV file:
cat time_test.csv 
book, 2022-08-13 13:30:01,out
char,2022-08-13 13:35:22, inside 
lather,2022-08-13 13:36:00, out

Create the table:
create table item (
    name Text,
    t Time without time zone,
    status Text);

Import the data using psql:
\copy item from time_test.csv with csv
COPY 3

The result:
  name  |    t     |  status  
--------+----------+----------
 book   | 13:30:01 | out
 char   | 13:35:22 |  inside 
 lather | 13:36:00 |  out

The datetime string will automatically be cast to time on import.

That's because timestamp literals work as valid time literals. Postgres simply discards the leading date part. That's implemented in basic I/O routines, no cast required.

Sections Type casts and Constants of Other Types beg to differ.

and why when im doing it in pgadmin its not working? only on the psql it will work?

its not working is pretty vague, nobody has access to your database and or computer. pgAdmin is just a SQL client, like psql, Navicat, DBeaver, DataGrip, etc. Most of these have their own implementation of COPY

\copy is specific to psql. If you want to import from a CSV file in pgAdmin4 use the Import/Export dialog. Though my suggestion is learn to use psql you will be more productive.

@Adrian Is your comment on type casts in response to my comment? (confused)
